# Can I specify multiple parameters using WhenInjectedInto for ninject?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject

When setting up my ninject bindings, I'm using the .ToMethod to specify particular parameters for specific connectionstrings, and the WhenInjectedInto method to constrain the binding to specific types:

```
        Bind(Of IDbConnection).ToMethod(Function(context) New OracleConnection(ConnectionStringFactory.GetConnection(DBC.ConnectionStrings.Oracle))).WhenInjectedInto(Of AccountBalancesLookup)()
        Bind(Of IDbConnection).ToMethod(Function(context) New OracleConnection(ConnectionStringFactory.GetConnection(DBC.ConnectionStrings.Oracle))).WhenInjectedInto(Of MFUtility)()
```

My question is, can I do something like this:

```
        Bind(Of IDbConnection).ToMethod(Function(context) New OracleConnection(ConnectionStringFactory.GetConnection(DBC.ConnectionStrings.Oracle))).WhenInjectedInto(Of AccountBalancesLookup, MFUtility)()
```

Specifying more than one destination for the binding at once, rather than having multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. But you can create your own extension to `When(Func<IRequest,bool>)` which does exactly that. For example:

```
public static class WhenExtensions
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInjectedInto<T>(
        this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax, params Type[] types)
    {
        var conditions = ComputeMatchConditions(syntax, types).ToArray();
        return syntax.When(request => conditions.Any(condition => condition(request)));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Func<IRequest, bool>> ComputeMatchConditions<T>(
        IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax, Type[] types)
    {
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            syntax.WhenInjectedInto(type);
            yield return syntax.BindingConfiguration.Condition;
        }
    }
}
```

used like:

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant("Hello")
            .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(SomeTypeA), typeof(SomeTypeB));

        kernel.Bind<string>().ToConstant("Goodbye")
            .WhenInjectedInto<SomeTypeC>();

        kernel.Get<SomeTypeA>().S.Should().Be("Hello");
        kernel.Get<SomeTypeB>().S.Should().Be("Hello");

        kernel.Get<SomeTypeC>().S.Should().Be("Goodbye");
    }
}

public abstract class SomeType
{
    public string S { get; private set; }

    protected SomeType(string s)
    {
        S = s;
    }
}

public class SomeTypeA : SomeType
{
    public SomeTypeA(string s) : base(s) { }
}

public class SomeTypeB : SomeType
{
    public SomeTypeB(string s) : base(s) { }
}

public class SomeTypeC : SomeType
{
    public SomeTypeC(string s) : base(s) { }
}
```

Note that `ComputeMatchConditions` is kind of a hack because it relies on ninject internals.. if these (the implementation of `WhenInjectedInto`) change then this may stop to work. Of course you're free to provide your own alternative implementation. You could also copy the code from `WhenInjectedInto`, see: [BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs method `WhenInjectedInto(Type parent)`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs)