# How do I create Ninject bindings with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, ninject

Is it possible to create bindings by combining conditions? For eg combining .WhenInjectedExactlyInto and WhenParentNamed ? Typically I end up using the When syntax and incorporating the Ninject source code for those methods but I'm wondering if there's a generic way to do this.

Comment: Sounds like you need factories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic way to do so (out of the box) other than to use the `When` method which you're already doing.

The problem is that the relevant condition "predicates" in the ninject code are not publicly accessible, so you end up copying ninject's code.

I'd suggest creating an issue on https://github.com/ninject/ninject and providing a Pull Request (PR) which makes the relevant code part `public` so they can be reused externally.

Comment: The predicates themselves aren't accessible but they can be accessed after they've been applied via the BuilderConfiguration.Condition property which is public. This way you can combine them, which is what I ended up doing. It's not ideal though since it does mean that you have to assume that the builder is BindingConfigurationBuilder<T> but i can live with that for now.

Comment: @AmitG yes that's true, using that is an approach i've also shown in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784103/can-i-specify-multiple-parameters-using-wheninjectedinto-for-ninject/30787518#30787518) answer. It works but it would be so much cleaner if these predicates would be available `public`